# Angular databinding as a function argument not working

Tags: angularjs

```
<input type="text" value="{{codes[0].code}}" ng-click="newNumber(0)" />
<input type="text" value="{{codes[1].code}}" ng-click="newNumber({{codes[1].id}})" />
```

The first ng-click event fires in my controller just fine but the second one does nothing.

I tried concat'ing as well ... is there some other way I should do this?

Comment: Try `ng-click="newNumber(codes[1].id)"`.  Why you are using `value` instead of `ng-model`?

Comment: I am still trying to grasp the concept of Models in Angular .. I define the $scope.codes object (model) in the controller.  Maybe I should go back and re-read....now that I am actuall DOING, its starting to become all a little more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ng-click

The value of `ng-click` is already evaluated as an angular expression. As such, you don't need the `{{ }}`. Read http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression for more information. Take a look at the second example, it will help clarify this.

## ng-model

Also, `ng-model` should be used for data-binding. For example, take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bCpW9/8/ and the notes below.

`<li ng-repeat="code in codes">`

This loops through the `codes` collection which was defined in the controller. It creates a `<li>` for each element in the `codes` collection.

`<input ng-model="codes[$index].code" />`

Inside each `<li>`, an `<input>` for the current code is created. Each `input` is bound to it's corresponding element in the `codes` array by setting `ng-model` to it. For instance, type a new code into the first `input` field. It automatically updates the corresponding `code` model with what you typed, as you can see to the right.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, great information!!!  But I STILL dont know why the function in ng-click should be newNumber(code[$index].id) which works BTW and not newNumber({{code[$index].id}});  ... ?

Comment: The value of `ng-click` is already evaluated as an angular expression. As such, you don't need the {{}}.

Comment: Read http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression for more information. Take a look at the second example, it will help clarify this.

Comment: BRENT - could you please add this to your answer above so I can check it as answer.  Thanks!